# where is "application servers" tab in IntelliJ 11.1.3

Tags: ide, intellij-idea

can't find application servers tab in IDE setting, as it was in previous versions

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I am using 11.1.3 Ultimate and it's there. Maybe you are missing some plugin?

If you still can't find it, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> (*Enter action or option name*) and type "*application servers*". Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> and IntelliJ will open proper window.

UPDATE: application servers are [not supported in community edition](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html).

Comment: @Herokiller: application servers are [not supported in community edition](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html)

Comment: Is community edition not allowed to add application servers still ?

Comment: @AjayS No it dont